# Culture info comma doesn't read my decimal as decimal

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

The value of my_waste in db which I enter with comma is:

```
16.78
```

I make a selection via linq and:

```
res.Add("testdb", p.my_waste);
```

and i get 1678.

I tried:

```
res.Add("test", double.Parse(p.my_waste.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

and

```
res.Add("test", string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.00}", p.my_waste));
```

And I still got 1678.

Comment: When you debug this and inspect `p.my_waste` I guess the value is 1678. How do you *get* that value from the database into that property/field? And what is the type?

Comment: Yup, calling `double.Parse(p.my_waste.ToString(), ?)` is useless if `p.my_waste` is already `1678`.

Comment: What is `p.my_waste.GetType()`?

Comment: @HansKesting p.my_waste in the db is float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)

> The invariant culture is culture-insensitive; it is associated with the English language but not with any country/region.

This means that it expects numbers to have a decimal point as English (all variants) uses a decimal point not a decimal comma.

If you are inputting data with a decimal comma you need to use a culture (e.g. French) that has a decimal comma to to the string <-> number conversion.

At the moment the comma is being treated as a thousands separator and is effectively ignored, so "16,78" comes out as 1678 as you have observed.